Formatting superscript/exponents in excel
So my issue here is that I have a column of numbers (xxx,xxx). And another column of Superscript numbers that are the exponents for the first column. I have had some kind of success with a lot of them using eg (A1 & CHAR(xx) for superscript 1.
I have a superscript exponent of 1.5, whatever I change (calculating manual, auto format off), or if I format to text, number, or scientific notation; it is not keeping the subscript from the previous column.
It's for a lab in my hydrology class.
eg.

Becomes 3590002 when removing the quotations.
Thanks for any help!

Please edit your question to include the code used to create that string. I suspect you may need to enter the entire value as a string.

Put an apostrophe before your exponent and format it as superscript. Such a number is formally a text, however it is converted to number in calculations.


We could define a few named functions to get the desired textual respresentation with superscript.

There is no superscript character for decimal point, so here I'm using U+0307 ◌̇ COMBINING DOT ABOVE, combined with spaces.
Define three functions:

d2sup: substitute digits to superscript conterparts
n2sup: format number with superscript
exp2sup: format (num, exponent) with superscript



We could test it with:
=LET(
    d2sup, LAMBDA(num,
        INDEX(
            {"⁰", "¹", "²", "³", "⁴", "⁵", "⁶", "⁷", "⁸", "⁹", "̇   "},
            1,
            FIND(num, "0123456789.")
        )
    ),
    n2sup, LAMBDA(num,
        REDUCE(
            num,
            MID(num, SEQUENCE(LEN(num)), 1),
            LAMBDA(acc, cur, SUBSTITUTE(acc, cur, d2sup(cur)))
        )
    ),
    exp2sup, LAMBDA(n, x, n & " " & n2sup(x)),
    exp2sup(23, 1.5)
)

Then we can define these in the Name Manager:

and use anywhere in the workbook:
=exp2sup(23,1.5)

Using with your sample numbers:

